# How can I get time difference on .NET without counting days?

Tags: .net, datetime, c++-cli, timespan

I'm using the classes DateTime and TimeSpan in order to check if I'm near to an hour given by parameters.

I'm doing exactly the next:

```
    DateTime current_time = DateTime::Now;

    //When 'time' is the DateTime value defined by parameter
    TimeSpan diff_time = current_time - CurrentConfig->Config_data->dbg->time;
    double diff_seconds = Math::Abs(diff_time.TotalSeconds);

    bool close = false;
    //time_lib_mem = 30s
    if (diff_seconds <= CurrentConfig->Config_data->dbg->time_lib_mem ){
        close = true;
    }
```

My problem is that days also count on the difference. How can I do for ignoring the day difference, so I can only check if I'm near to one target hour without caring about the day?

I thought that one solution could be to sustract 24*60*60 seconds until my second difference is minor to 24*60*60, but that's not a good solution because my app will run for a long time, so the loop of difference will do one more lap each day.

Is there any way to ignore the days on the difference?

Thank you.

Comment: Use current_time.TimeOfDay

Comment: Simply. And worked perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Depending on your requirements, you might need to "be close" during a short period at most once during each day. You might also need to catch up if you missed it. So, be careful with Daylight Saving Time changes, etc.